# Inserting Hebrew data into mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, hebrew

i'm facing an issue with inserting hebrew data from my php web page into mysql database.
my collation for the table is utf8_general_ci.
this is the php script

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<body style="background-color:#990000;"> 
<h5 align="center" style="font-family:tahoma;color:white;font-size:45px;"> Fill A Question! </h5>
<form align="center" method="post" action="addask.php">
Course Number: <input type="text" name="CourseNum"><br>
Ask: <input align="20px" type="text" name="ask"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Ask">
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
session_start();
$UserID = $_SESSION['UserID'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
if ((isset($_POST['CourseNum'])) && (isset($_POST['ask'])))
{
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = 'password';
    $db = 'jonatandb';
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
    if (!$conn)
    {
        die ('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Asks (UserID,Course_Num,Ask) VALUES ('$UserID','$_POST[CourseNum]','$_POST[ask]')";
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
?>
```

when i try to insert hebrew data into my database with INSERT DATA directly from the mysql command line, it works fine.

Thank you!.

---

Comment: The inserted data in the database itself is wrong? Or just when you display it in the browser via your php script?

Comment: Mind telling us what exactly is wrong? "I'm facing an issue but it works elsewhere" gives us nothing to troubleshoot on.

Comment: when i insert the data in hebrew i get gibberisht. i mean the data in the database is gibberish.

Comment: You are running `mysql_set_charset` after `mysqli_query`. Try running it before.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf-8'");
mysql_set_charset('utf-8',$conn);
```

Sometimes one or the other works.

### EDIT

Change your form to this:

```
<form action="addask.php" action="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

You'll also need to know if your database is using the format utf-8 or uft8. To find out, insert some Hebrew into your database, and try extracting it with both.

Also, you don't need both the UTF-8 meta and header. I have read having the meta slows down web browsers and the best solution is to set as UTF-8 in .htaccess

http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-htaccess-charset.en

But I can't vouch for that.

Comment: i didnt understand what you mean.

Comment: In your mysql connection functions you are using utf8, try changing this to utf-8. You use 'utf8' twice.

Comment: Try removing header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');, but keep the header. Also try printing out the posted data INTO THE HTML when page reloads. If that displays fine, at least it can be narrowed down to a MySQL problem.